# C-modifying the address of a global variable inside a void function

Tags: c, pointers, global-variables

Working on a linked list where I'm storing a pointer to head as a global variable. My question is: How can I assign a (new)value (in this case address) to head from within a void function?

**EDIT**

Alright here's some code:
Note: this is not how i would design this, but we're not supposed to stray from the spec.

```
typedef struct NODE Node;
typedef Node *NodePtr;

struct NODE{
        char *item;
        Node *next;
};


NodePtr first = NULL; //global


//insert function
Boolean insert( char *new_string ) {
        printf("insert called\n");

        if(first == NULL) {
                first = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                first->next = NULL;
                first->item = new_string;
        }
        else {
                NodePtr inserted  = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                inserted->next = first;
                inserted->item = new_string;
                first = inserted;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

the problem is that when i use insert() in a function. it works fine. i get a working list. but when another function tries to access first, its empty.

Am I right in assuming that modifying the global variables within the function does not alter the actual first ptr? I know I could pass in a pointer to first as an argument, but I'm not supposed to modify the prototype design.

Comment: Be more clear in your questions

Comment: "How can I modify the value of a global variable from within a void function ?' isnt clear?

Comment: It's in scope - change it.

Comment: If it's not in scope, make the void function non-void.

Comment: Just a comment: just before you assign a new address to the head (and since you mentioned _head_ I assumed it's a simple linked list), are you freeing the old value (or the whole list)?

Comment: Since it's a global variable, you can just assign to it directly. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass in the pointer and a pointer to pointer to head.. Update pointer to head, and head-> next to old head

Comment: Why does he need to pass it in if it's a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

if it is a global variable just assign the value like you would have done if it was a local variable in your void function.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your struct is similar to this:

```
struct list {
    int data;
    struct list* next;
};
```

and you have the global variable

```
struct list* L
```

you can make a new node by making a new node, making the next variable to the head, and making your global value point to the new node:

```
newnode->next = L;
L = newnode
```